# Differentiate between a name and a href

Tags: html, css

In CSS, I want to set different attributes for

```
<a name="tag">one font and color</a>
```

and

```
<a href="link">a different font and color</a>
```

However, setting the attributes for the `<a>` tag make both pieces of text have the same color. How can I make them different? Do I have to put an `id` on every single one?

Comment: If you really want to determine CSS attributes based on attributes besides class and id (which is preferred) you can use `a[name="tag"] { ... }` or `a[href="link"] { ... }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you would have an anchor tag, without an `href`.

The purpose of the `name` attribute, is for forms, so that when you submit a form, you can retrieve the data.

In order to style HTML elements, you'll want to use either an `id` or a `class`. A `class` can be used multiple times on a page, where an `id` can only be used once per page.

It's absolutely possible to style an anchor tag based on the attribute like so:

```
a[name] {
  /* Style 1 */
}
a[name="tag"] {
  /* Style 2 */
}
a[href] {
  /* Style 3 */
}
a[href="link"] {
  /* Style 4 */
}
```

But it's best practice to use `id` and `class`.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```css
a[name] {
  color: blue;
}


a[name="tag"] {
  color: red;
}
a[href] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a name="tag">A with name as tag</a><br>
<a name="haha">A with name attribute set</a><br>
<a href="link">one font and color</a>
```

It will set different CSS styles based on attributes

Answer (score 0):

probably  you just apply below css :

```
a {
   color : red;
   ....
}
```

This css applys to all a tags in html document.
Instead to apply a css to a specific a tag, Do this:
Html :

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Css :

```
#mylink {
   color:blue;
 }
```

This css just applys to the element which has an id of mylink, for furthur inf comment me .

NOTE : only one element can have a specific id. If you want to use for several elements use class.
Html:

```
<a class="links">Test</a>
<a class="links2">Google</a>
<a class = "links">Yahoo</a>
```

Css :

```
.links {   /*This applys to 'a' tas which have <<class="links">> */
   color:blue;
   font-size:12pt
   ....
   }

 .links2 {
  ...
  }
```

There are more ways like inheritation and according to a attribute. For more information comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes for each Anchor tag. It can be used by the tags having similar properties.
See this example.

```css
.tag1{
    font-family:verdana;
    color:red;
}
.tag2{
    font-family:cursive;
    color:green;
}
.tag3{
    font-family:arial;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<a href = "#"class="tag1">one font and color</a><br/>
<a href="link" class="tag2" >a different font and color</a><br />
<a href="link" class="tag3" >a different font and color</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use inline styling like this:

```
    <a href="link" style="color: color;">stuff</a>
```